# python - web scraping - return attributes from inside a class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to return the value of 'data-pages' from from inside the snippet of html below (snipped from a whole page).

```
   <div class="catalogPagination" data-js-component="catalog-pagination/catalog-pagination">
    <span class="catalogPagination_button catalogPagination_button-prev catalogPagination_button-disabled">
    </span>
    <div class="catalogPagination_label">
     <select class="catalogPagination_dropdown" data-baseurl="/herrenbekleidung-shirts/?order=popularity" data-current="1" data-pages="97">
      <option>
       Seite 1 von 97
      </option>
     </select>
```

I am using BeautifulSoup, and my code prints 'None' whenever I try to use soup.find()

```
s = soup.find('data-pages', attrs={'class': 'catalogPagination_dropdown'})
print s
```

Could someone show me what I am doing wrong? and the correct way to get this value from the class?

Also, if I wanted to extend this to return all the values of 'data-pages' across the entire site, how would this be done?

```
s = soup.find_all(.....) ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add more of the html or a link to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the attribute from the tag:

```
print([s["data-pages"] for s in soup.select("select.catalogPagination_dropdown") if s.has_attr("data-pages")])
```

`select.catalogPagination_dropdown` will find all the select tags across the entire page with the `catalogPagination_dropdown` class then you just need to  extract the data-pages attribute if it has the attribute we want.

You can also use find_all, using  `"data-pages": True` to only find the tags with the `data-current` attribute in case some don't have it:

```
html = """ <div class="catalogPagination" data-js-component="catalog-pagination/catalog-pagination">
    <span class="catalogPagination_button catalogPagination_button-prev catalogPagination_button-disabled">
    </span>
    <div class="catalogPagination_label">
     <select class="catalogPagination_dropdown" data-baseurl="/herrenbekleidung-shirts/?order=popularity" data-current="1" data-pages="97">
      <select class="catalogPagination_dropdown" data-baseurl="/herrenbekleidung-shirts/?order=popularity" data-current="1" foo="97">

      <option>
       Seite 1 von 97
      </option>
     </select>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


selects = soup.find_all("select", {"class": "catalogPagination_dropdown", "data-pages": True})

print([s["data-pages"] for s in selects])
```

Which will give you the same as the select with your example html but it ignore the select with foo in place of data-pages that I added:

```
['97']
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you have attached bigger html snippet.

If the tag's name is `select` you have to change attributes in `soup.find(..)` and if you want to get attributes value, you have to attach ['data-pages']

Try this:

```
s = soup.find('select', attrs={'class': 'catalogPagination_dropdown'})['data-pages']
print s
```

Comment: How do you get page source? Try to print the source and check for this tag in the source. It could be dynamically generated or it could be more than one select tags there with the class catalogPagination.... so It takes the first. If the first does not contain data-pages attribute, you get None. Check Padraic's answer.